# Evenly shuffling a list of mail address by domain

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a list of email address which I want to distribute evenly by domain.

For example:

let the list be,

```
a@a.com
b@a.com
c@a.com
a@b.com
b@b.com
c@c.com
```

The output should be

```
a@a.com
a@b.com
c@c.com
b@a.com
b@b.com
c@a.com
```

The source list is not sorted by domain as in example, but can be sorted by domain, if that can help. What would be an efficient (single/two pass?) algorithm of doing this?

raj

Comment: OK, might I ask _why_ you want to shuffle them?  If it's to evenly distribute e-mail traffic to each of the domains, then don't.  It's more efficient to have mail for the same domain be delivered all at the same time, as they can share an SMTP connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem. Given an input like

```
[["A", 13], ["B", 5], ["C", 3], ["D", 1]]
```

The output is

```
AABABAACABAACABAACABAD
```

Ruby source of the program is:

```
require "pp"

def shuffle (total, num)
  ret_arr = Array.new
  intervel = total/num.to_f
  0.upto(num-1) do |i|
    val = i * intervel
    ret_arr << val.floor
  end
  return ret_arr
end

freq_table = [["A", 13], ["B", 5], ["C", 3], ["D", 1]]

pp freq_table
total = 0
freq_table.collect {|i| total += i[1] }
final_array = Array.new(total,0)
print  final_array.to_s + "\n\n"
placed = 0

freq_table.each do |i|
  placements =  shuffle(total - placed, i[1])
  placements.each do |j|
    free_index = -1
    0.upto final_array.size do |k|
      free_index += 1 if (final_array[k] == 0 || final_array[k] == i[0])
      if j == free_index
        final_array[k] = i[0]
        break
      end
    end
  end
  print "Placing #{i[1]} #{i[0]}s over #{total - placed} positions\n"
  pp placements
  print  final_array.to_s + "\n\n"
  placed += i[1]
end
```

The idea is to take the alphabet with highest frequency and distribute it first across an array whose size is the total number of all elements. Next distribute the alphabet with second highest frequency and distribute it across the free spaces and so on.

If you have questions let me know and I am happy to answer.

raj

Answer (score 1):

Beware of answers that assume that the number of email addresses per domain are the same (or similar).

I tried to solve essentially the same problem, and it received a lot of discussion on my blog: [First Article](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2007/01/18/wine-gum-selection-puzzle/), [Second Article](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2007/11/02/wine-gumpodcast-selection-algorithm-solution/)

We didn't find a fast, optimal solution, but the [fastest, close-enough solution](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2007/11/02/wine-gumpodcast-selection-algorithm-solution/#comment-73241) (including Perl source code) came from a comment from [Aristotle Pagaltzis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9410/aristotle-pagaltzis).

Kudos to Aristotle.

Answer (score 0):

My starting attempt would be a hash map of linked lists, so that once all the domain collisions were grouped, you could iterate though the linked lists one at a time.

If that makes any sense.

The following code is completely **UNTESTED**, and I know there is a bunch of stuff not right in the second loop, but it was faster than trying to explain further.

```
$sortedList = array();
$tempList
$emailList = array('a@a.com', 'b@a.com', 'c@b.com', 'd@b.com', 'e@c.com', 'f@a.com');

$emailCount = 0;
foreach ( $emailList as $email ) {
    list($username, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
    $tempList[$domain][] = $user;
    $emailCount++;
}

for ( $i = 0; $i < $emailCount; $i++ ) {
    $listIndex = $i % count($tempList);
    if ( !empty($tempList[$listIndex]) ) {
        $sortedList[] = $tempList[$listIndex][0];
        unset($tempList[$listIndex][0]);
    } else {
        unset$tempList[$listIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, for each email address, put the address into linked-list for given domain.  That's an O(n) operation, then creating a new, balanced list is another roughly O(n) operation by cycling through the domain lists.

That's about 2-pass complexity, as ordered.